# Binding an input range control with Angular.js not binding value after re-setting the data model

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of rows, each with it's own slider/range input.

````html
<tr ng-repeat="(ndx, row) in filteredData track by $index">
  ...
  <td>
    <input type="range" class="range pull-left"
      ng-init="row.Qty"
      ng-model="row.Qty"
      style="font-size: .9em; padding: 8px 0px 0px 2px;"
      min="0"
      step="{{row.CaseQty}}"
      max="{{row.MaxQty}}" />
  </td>
  ...
</tr>
```
````

This data is initialized after the user initiates an online search.  When the data is returned, the respecting collection is initialized.  Specifically, this is how I initialize `filteredData` in my `$scope` object.

```js
$scope.getCOOrders = function () {
    $scope.gridFilters.customerId = "";
    $http.post("...", {/*set filters*/})
       .success(function (data) {
          if (data.Status !== "OK") {
            $scope.error(data, data.StatusMessage);
            return;
          }
          $scope.data = data.Rows;
          $scope.filteredData = data.Rows;
        })
        .error(function (data) {
          $scope.error(data, "There was a problem getting the orders.");
        });
      };
```

This works.  For each row, if there is a non-zero value for `row.Qty`, it will properly initialize the slider value.  However, I have a couple of controls that allow for filtering from the browser so that the collection used for the rows can be managed locally.  This is why the table binds to the `$scope.filteredData` object ratehr than the `$scope.data` object.

This is what the filter method looks like.  It was initially a single-line, but I expanded it to inspect these values in Visual Studio.

```js
$scope.filterGrid = function () {

  //I also added this line, just to clear the collection.
  //This did not help or change the results.
  $scope.filteredData = [];

  //NOTE: $scope.orderCheckFilters is just the method used to check the row values. It does not modify their values.
  var arr = $scope.data.filter($scope.orderCheckFilters);
  $scope.filteredData = arr;
};
```

The above method will filter the list, however, my range controls no longer show the sliders at their correct value position on the range slider.

You may ask if there is a chance that the filter is removing the value from the bound field?  No.  I have a label next to each range slider. It's bound value is always correct. However, the sliders are not being initialized only after the user filters the list from within the browser.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After the line below:

```
var arr = $scope.data.filter($scope.orderCheckFilters);
$scope.filteredData = arr;
```

Array.filter will return a new object, so u have changed the memory location of filteredData, which is a filtered version of $scope.data. At this point itself, it has lost all information which is there in $scope.filteredData before this line and not there in $scope.data

So, Basically, filteredData and filters themselves can't be in the same object.

Let the $scope.data constant, as u anyway are doing, but use range values from $scope.data and have filteredData separately.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to pipe the `ng-repeat` to a filter expression:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(ndx, row) in data | filter : predicateFn">
  ...
  <td>
    <input type="range" class="range pull-left"
      ng-model="row.Qty"
      style="font-size: .9em; padding: 8px 0px 0px 2px;"
      min="0"
      step="{{row.CaseQty}}"
      max="{{row.MaxQty}}" />
  </td>
  ...
</tr>
```

Where `$scope.predicateFn` is a function with signature: function(value, index, array). A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The function is called for each element of the array, with the element, its index, and the entire array itself as arguments.

The final result is an array of those elements for which the predicate returned `true`.

For more inforamtion, see

- [AngularJS `filter` Filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Comment: Just so I understand this approach, when my users enter their search texts in the text input fields, all I have to do from my filter method is change the associated $scope model values, and `predicateFn` will know to execute?  In other words, I see what this is doing, but how does the grid know when to reevaluate `predicateFn`?